# Sending notifications from Wordpress OneSignal plugins on Viewport Android App

Tags: android, wordpress, onesignal

I have a news website based on WordPress, I send notifications using OneSignal plugin, recently I created Android webview app, the notifications received on mobiles when clicked the article open in a browser instead of the App itself.

According to OneSignal documentation, I should create a most used plugin file "mu-plugin" including this PHP functions :

```
<?php
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);
function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    /* Goal: We don't want to modify the original $fields array, because we want the original web push notification to go out unmodified. However, we want to send an additional notification to Android and iOS devices with an additionalData property.
     *     */
    $fields_dup = $fields;
    $fields_dup['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields_dup['isIos'] = true;
    $fields_dup['isAnyWeb'] = true;
    $fields_dup['isWP'] = false;
    $fields_dup['isAdm'] = false;
    $fields_dup['isChrome'] = false;
    // $fields_dup['android_channel_id'] = "<CHANNEL ID UUID HERE>";
    $fields_dup['data'] = array("myappurl" => $fields['url']);
    /* Important to set web_url to support opening through both mobile and browser*/
    $fields_dup['web_url'] = $fields_dup['url'];
    /* Important to unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked for mobile app users */
    unset($fields_dup['url']);
    $onesignal_post_url = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";
    /* Hopefully OneSignal::get_onesignal_settings(); can be called outside of the plugin */
    $onesignal_wp_settings = OneSignal::get_onesignal_settings();
    $onesignal_auth_key = $onesignal_wp_settings['app_rest_api_key'];
    $request = array("headers" => array("content-type" => "application/json;charset=utf-8", "Authorization" => "Basic " . $onesignal_auth_key), "body" => json_encode($fields_dup), "timeout" => 60);
    $response = wp_remote_post($onesignal_post_url, $request);
    if (is_wp_error($response) || !is_array($response) || !isset($response['body'])) {
        $status = $response->get_error_code();
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        error_log("There was a " . $status . " error returned from OneSignal when sending to mobile users: " . $error_message);
        return;
    }
    return $fields;
}

?>
```

Now the notification open up the mobile app instead of browser, but showing the home page instead of the article it self.

Note: If I use OneSignal dashboard to send notification, and I unset the "Launch URL", then add in "Additional Data" the following fields :

- Key : URL
- Value : The post url

Then the notification will open the mobile app with deep linking to the article page.

Anyone can help me modify the function ?

Thanks :)